Re arrange multidimentional array
I have an multi dimensional array i am trying to group the array based on the duplicate value.
So, I'm trying to group them by key but i am not getting to group the array based on the key values.
Below is the original array
[
    {
        "league_id": 2,
        "league_name": "BBBB",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1722361078.png",
        "order_number": 1,
        "member_username": "A"
    },
    {
        "league_id": 2,
        "league_name": "BBBB",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1722361078.png",
        "order_number": 2,
        "member_username": "B"
    },
    {
        "league_id": 1,
        "league_name": "AAAA",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1724177635.png",
        "order_number": 1,
        "member_username": "C"
    },
    {
        "league_id": 1,
        "league_name": "AAAA",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1724177635.png",
        "order_number": 2,
        "member_username": "D"
    },
]

I want to rearrange this array as output array below:
[
    {
        "league_id": 2,
        "league_name": "BBBB",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1722361078.png",
        "users": [{
            "order_number": 1,
            "member_username": "A"
        }, {
            "order_number": 2,
            "member_username": "B"
        }]
    },
    {
        "league_id": 1,
        "league_name": "AAAA",
        "league_image": "https://d2ayu7u0r0spqb.cloudfront.net/dev/league-images/1722361078.png",
        "users": [{
            "order_number": 1,
            "member_username": "C"
        }, {
            "order_number": 2,
            "member_username": "D"
        }]
    }
]

Any idea? How to do this.
Thanks

I don't see arrays here. I see JSON.

Thanks to @Olivier, for pointing out bug that would add all the users to $final_array except the current iteration one.
I think a foreach loop would do the trick for you.
Example Implementation:
$array = []; // Your original array here
$final_array = []; // Initializing an empty array to store final result

foreach ($array as $item) {
    // Check if item's league id is already present in $final_array or not
    if (isset($final_array[$item['league_id']])) {
        // If yes, then add to users
        $final_array[$item['league_id']]['users'][] = [
            "order_number" => $item['order_number'],
            "member_username" => $item['member_username']
        ];
    } else {
        // If no, then add as a new element
        $final_array[$item['league_id']] = [
            "league_id" => $item['league_id'],
            "league_name" => $item['league_name'],
            "league_image" => $item['league_image'],
            "users" => [
                "order_number" => $item['order_number'],
                "member_username" => $item['member_username']
            ]
        ];
    }
}

// Uncomment the following line if you want to sort the $final_array according to league ids.
// $final_array = ksort($final_array);

// Since you need a non-associative array
$final_array = array_values($final_array);

echo $final_array; // The $final_array contains your desired array

Hence, the $final_array is the required array.
I know this is NOT the most optimal or most efficient solution, but if your array is not much big, the above implementation would be enough for you.

There is nothing wrong with performance here. The only issue is that you create an empty users array for new ids; it should contain an entry.

Oh, sorry, I just forgot that. I am updating my answer.
